# Trouble using mouse to click on JComponent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent, mouselistener

Hey Everyone I am trying to create a somewhat dynamic program in which you can add shapes or images to a JPanel and then select and move the shapes after you have added them. The problem is that when I click on the specific JComponent nothing happens. In fact clicking on any of the components I have created to test the project returns false for all JComponents. However it seems that if I click inside the bounds of my JComponent in the top left corner I will get returned true for all JComponents, ie click in the area bounded by (0,0,50,68).

The idea is that if I click one of the JComponents it will set that specific JComponent to be movable however I cannot get past the part of actually selecting a specific JComponent.

Here is a basic SSCE that I built to recreate the problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCE1 extends JPanel {
private ArrayList<Shape> shapeList = new ArrayList<Shape>();

SSCE1() {
    setLayout(null);
    /* Debug Stuff */
    System.out.println("Debug:");
    /* Add The First Shape To The List */
    shapeList.add(0, new Shape(100, 100));
    add(shapeList.get(0));
    shapeList.add(1, new Shape(610, 0));
    add(shapeList.get(1));
    shapeList.add(2, new Shape(500, 900));
    add(shapeList.get(2));

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            for (Shape shape : shapeList) {
                if (shape.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
}

class Shape extends JComponent {
int xLocation, yLocation, xBounds1, yBounds1;

Shape(int xLocation, int yLocation) {
    this.xLocation = xLocation;
    this.yLocation = yLocation;
    this.xBounds1 = 50;
    this.yBounds1 = 68;
    setBounds(xLocation, yLocation, xBounds1, yBounds1);
    setLocation(xLocation, yLocation);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

}
}

class Run {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame main = new JFrame();
    SSCE1 p1 = new SSCE1();
    main.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setLocation(new Point(0, 0));
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.add(p1);
}
```

}

Comment: What's shape, how's it defined?

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @MadProgrammer it JComponent, determine below

Comment: Sorry, missing scroll bars :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next mouseListener it works:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            for (Shape shape : shapeList) {
                Point convertPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(SSCE1.this, e.getPoint(), shape);
                if (shape.contains(convertPoint)) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

The reason is next according [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#contains%28java.awt.Point%29) in `contains` method `the point's x and y coordinates are defined to be relative to the coordinate system of this component.` because of that works for (0,0,50,68). All what you need convert point from `JPanel` to `Shape` with help of `SwingUtilities.convertPoint(...)`

Comment: Thank you, I never would of thought of that

Comment: I am at work right now, I will try this who  I get home but if you don't mind how does this work? I guess I don't get how the conversion from source coordinate system to destination coordinate system works

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the problem is, `Shape` is expecting any mouse coordinates you pass it to be defined within the context of the `Shape`.  That is, the top, left corner of `Shape` is always `0x0`

The mouse point you are processing is within the context of the parent container, therefore, unless `Shape` is positioned at `0x0` within the parent container, `Shape` will never contain the mouse point.

You need to translate the mouse point to the context of the `Shape` before checking it

For example...

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        for (Shape shape : shapeList) {
            Point shapePoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(e.getComponent(), e.getPoint(), shape);
            if (shape.contains(shapePoint) {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
            }
        }

    }
});
```